# Probability and averages

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

There are 16 bulbs in a lot. Probability of one being defective is 0.001. What is average number of defective bulbs?

Comment: "defective", not "defected".  What do you think the answer is?

Comment: If you don't add a description of your own work, the question will probably be closed quite fast.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$, a random variable, represents the number of defectives bulbs in a box with 
16 bulbs, when the probability of defective bulb is 0.001, then with the usual independence assumptions,

$X\sim \text{Binomial}(n=16,p=0.001)$

And $E(X)=16\times 0.001=0.016$ bulbs. For a binomial r.v. the expected value is just $n\times p$.

Comment: Actually I was searching for the expected value and variance of Binomial Distribution. I was looking for its proof.

Comment: The easiest way to prove is observing that a Binomial random variable is the sum of $n$ independent and identical Bernoulli random variables with probability $p$ of success.